# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) when updating environ

Tags: python, django

I am using environment key for better settings configuration. Initially, i got the following error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable
```

thus, i searched in google and found the following solution

**settings/base.py**

```
import os

with open('.envs/.local/.postgres') as fh:
    os.environ.update(line.strip().split('=', 1) for line in fh)
```

However, this gives me an error too. I get

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

.postgres and .django looks like following

**.django**

```
# General
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export USE_DOCKER=yes

# Email
# DJANGO_EMAIL_BACKEND

# Redis
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0

# Celery
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CELERY_BROKER_URL=
# CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-cache'

# Flower
export CELERY_FLOWER_USER=debug
export CELERY_FLOWER_PASSWORD=debug
```

**.postgres**

```
# PostgreSQL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=database
POSTGRES_USER=username
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently not every line in `.envs/.local/.postgres` has an `=` character, so `split('=', 1)` results in only one item in the tuple it outputs for the line, while `dict.update` expects two items for every tuple in the iterator output.

You should make sure that there is an `=` character in the line in the generator expression:

```
os.environ.update(line.strip().split('=', 1) for line in fh if '=' in line)
```

EDIT: Now that you've updated your question with an additional `.django` file that has an extra keyword of `export` in front of the environment variable settings, you should look for this keyword and remove it if it exists:

```
os.environ.update((line.split(maxsplit=1)[1] if line.startswith('export ') else line).strip().split('=', 1) for line in fh if '=' in line)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by having an export in a line. Please post the content of your `.envs/.local/.postgres` if the above code doesn't work for you.

Comment: i did the same for both django and postgres but still it says USE_DOCKER=yes is not set.

Comment: You did not mention anything about `.django` or that it has an `export` keyword at all previously in your question. If there is `export` in `.django`, then of course additional code is needed to handle it. It isn't magic. You just have to strip `export` from the line if it exists. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: sorry i was jusst asking about export case and when you told update it with postgres, i updated django as well because I was not sure the main issue i raised was in postgres or django.